# how can I modify gvim to follow objects and variables to their definition?

Tags: eclipse, vim, vi

I am used to using (ctrl+click) on Eclipse and following variables/objects to look at the definition in order to understand the code.

I just started my first job and I only have access to unix (vi or gvim). Is it possible to do what I'm looking for?

edit: What I mean by is it possible? Lets say class foo is defined in file foo.hpp and is instantiated in foo.cpp. I want to be able to reach the definition of class foo from any instantiation of it in foo.cpp

Comment: Some things are possible, but you'll have to be a lot more specific as to what you're trying to do, in what language etc. Just "is it possible" won't do.

Comment: Just added more info to original question.

Comment: One of the various x-tags programs such as `ctags` should do the trick.  If that's not an option, then I think you're out of luck, unless you decide to use `cscope`.  But using `cscope` would be silly with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

With Vim you can use `tags` files generated by `exuberant-ctags` and other compatible programs.

"Tags" are function and variables, their name, signature and kind are stored alongside their location in files that Vim is able to parse to allow you to navigate through your code.

`:help tags` will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: user1035219: You might want to try it by pressing "CTRL+]" after you create tag file on method under your cursor.

Comment: `gd` and `gD` work only in the current file by default, that's why I didn't put it in the answer.